Is FilesMatch better than ProxyPassMatch for FPM in Apache?
I used to use ProxyPassMatch with a socket, worked flawlessly for years...
Recently, I have seen several posts and videos recommending the FilesMatch method, so I tried...
Haven't noticed any difference, hence my question:
Assuming Apache2 and PHP >=8.2 and FPM,
Is there any particular reason to favor FilesMatch over ProxyPassMatch or vice versa?
And if so, what would be the recommended settings and syntax.

Found this page to be very interesting, but I still have doubts:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/httpd/PHP-FPM

No noticeable difference, use whatever method suits you.
